# List of all installed packages in a defunct Homebrew installation?

Tags: homebrew

I have an old `homebrew` installation that is now not in use on a backup drive.  I'd like to list all of the packages that were installed when it was in use, how can this be done without mv'ing it back over to `/usr/local` and making it operational again?

Comment: What does this command produce?  `ls -1 /Volumes/*/usr/local/Cellar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Homebrew terminology](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/ac50ffc82d2590eed8d666464a7b0213e3db00d7/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md#homebrew-terminology), we have the following definitions :

> Cellar :  All Kegs are installed here
>
> Keg :      The installation prefix of a Formula
>
> Formula:   The package definition
>
> Homebrew installs to the Cellar it then symlinks some of the installation into /usr/local so that other programs can see what's going on.

As said in the comments, to list all packages previously installed on a backup drive you can do :

```
ls -1 /Volumes/*/usr/local/Cellar
```

If you want to have a better understanding of Homebrew paths, I recommend the reading of the following article : [The Path to Homebrew](http://rkulla.blogspot.ch/2014/03/the-path-to-homebrew.html).